# Bug in Python's documentation?

Tags: python, import, module

I am reading http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#more-on-modules and wonder if the following is correct:

> Modules can import other modules. It is customary but not required to
>   place all import statements at the beginning of a module (or script,
>   for that matter). **The imported module names are placed in the
>   importing module’s global symbol table.**

Apparently not:

```
>>> def foo(): import sys
... 
>>> foo()
>>> sys.path
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'sys' is not defined
```

See http://ideone.com/cLK09v for an online demo.

So, is it a bug in the Python's documentation or I don't understand something?

Comment: You can report about this on http://bugs.python.org .

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Done: http://bugs.python.org/issue17383

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, this is a documentation error. The `import` statement imports the names to the *current* namespace. Usually `import` is used outside of functions and classes, but as you've discovered, it does work within them. In your example function, the module is imported into the function's local namespace when the function is called. (Which you didn't do, but that wouldn't make it available outside the function anyway.)

The `global` keyword does work here, however:

```
def foo():
    global sys
    import sys

foo()
sys.path
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is actually an error in the documentation, but more of a mis-interpretation. You simply have a scope issue. You are importing it in the scope of the function foo(). You could certainly do as the documentation suggests and put the import at the bottom of the file or somewhere else in the file that would still have the same global scope as your module. The problem is "The imported module names are placed in the importing module’s global symbol table", where the scope of the module you are importing into is contained in the function foo(), not at the module's global level.